# AWS S3 AccessDenied on subfolder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

- I have created S3 bucket, and done the steps to enable static web hosting on it.
- I have verified it works by going to the URL 
  which looks something as following `https://my-bucket.s3.aws.com`
- I want to put my web assets in a sub folder now
- I put the web assets in a folder I called `foobar`
- Now if want to access it I have to explictly enter URL as following:
  `https://my-bucket.s3.aws.com/foobar/index.html`

So my question is, do I need to use some other service such as CloudFront to enable so I can go into the bucket with the following URL instead `https://my-bucket.s3.aws.com/foobar`, that is I don't want to have to explicit say `index.html` at the end?

Comment: Have you turned on the [S3 bucket static website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html)?

Comment: @jellycsc I wrote on the first bullet I have, and the second bullet I've written I've verified it works. Now I want it to work in a `subfolder` :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point. Why not try the website endpoint? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html

Comment: @jellycsc thanks I checked the page, and the endpoint examples on that page. It seems like by using S3 only I need to say the object name too when entering an URL. Whereas I'm looking for a way that it will redirect to `index.html` file when I go to a subfolder without explicitly having it in the URL.

Comment: try s3 redirection rules, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a default document for a subfolder using CloudFront.  [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html#DefaultRootObjectHow) says

> However, if you define a default root object, an end-user request for
> a subdirectory of your distribution does not return the default root
> object. For example, suppose index.html is your default root object
> and that CloudFront receives an end-user request for the install
> directory under your CloudFront distribution:
>
> http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/install/
>
> CloudFront does not return the default root object even if a copy of
> index.html appears in the install directory.

But that same page *also* says

> The behavior of CloudFront default root objects is different from the
> behavior of Amazon S3 index documents. When you configure an Amazon S3
> bucket as a website and specify the index document, Amazon S3 returns
> the index document even if a user requests a subdirectory in the
> bucket. (A copy of the index document must appear in every
> subdirectory.) For more information about configuring Amazon S3
> buckets as websites and about index documents, see the Hosting
> Websites on Amazon S3 chapter in the Amazon Simple Storage Service
> Developer Guide.

So check out out [that referenced guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html), and the section on [Configuring an Index Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/IndexDocumentSupport.html) in particular.

Comment: What if your s3 bucket isn't configured as website?! I don't have a root object (since that's all I read on SO as a suggestion). I can access objects within the root of the bucket, but can't for "subfolders".

Comment: When I browse the S3 bucket directly, index.html works for all subdirs. But when I browse through cloudfront (to get https) it doesn't work (giving access denied).